# Allowing subscription to all scheduled events for a chat room

Tags: feature-request, chat

I'd like to be able to subscribe to notifications of all scheduled events for a chat room. For example, I'd like notification of all [events in the SE Podcast Live Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/512/se-podcast-live-chat?tab=schedule) without needed to re-register each week or each time it's rescheduled.

Listing such users are "registered" would be misleading so they probably shouldn't be, or should be listed separately. In my case, I'd also like notification of each of [Gaming.SE's Game On! events](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/271/se-game-on?tab=schedule), but I wouldn't like to be listed as "registered" because I'm unlikely to participate in many of them.

Comment: You want SE to maintain an _implicit, rolling, tentative_ schedule for you? Unsure I agree.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I'd like notification of upcoming events, so I can determine if I want to participate. This currently requires checking back to the site repeatedly, which seems silly, as does requiring public registration (implying a commitment to participate) in order to get notified of events.